# Monitor starting/running/ending apps within node.js

Tags: node.js, monitoring

Is there a way to monitor starting/running/ending apps within node.js?

Like "You just started LibreOffice Writer!".
It would be nice if any of you cracks could help me with this.

Edit:
I am searching for something that runs in the background and is triggered whenever I run a random application/script/whatever has a system-wide pid.

Comment: I don't you can do that yet(never can) with node.js cleanly. I guess you could poll `ps`.

Comment: Sure. This would be an option, too. But is there a way to fetch this output in a collection for working with it more easily?

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this since?

Answer (score 3):

`forever` is a daemon manager for node.js that can do this.

http://thechangelog.com/post/6637623247/forever-node-js-daemon-manager

https://github.com/indexzero/forever

Or if you just want to start a process once and be able to manage it, you can use the builtin `ChildProcess`.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/child_processes.html

Comment: I guess forever is not what I am searching for. I will redefine my question to make it clearer.